# Clubbing three queries that return mutually exclusive records

Tags: performance, sql, oracle

There is a table in Oracle database with the following data

```
+----+-----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| Id | Key | Value | Is_Orig | Is_Prev | Is_Curr |
+----+-----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 |  10 |  1000 |       1 |       0 |       0 |
|  2 |  10 |  2000 |       0 |       0 |       0 |
|  3 |  10 |  3000 |       0 |       1 |       0 |
|  4 |  10 |  4000 |       0 |       0 |       1 |
|  5 |  20 |   100 |       1 |       0 |       0 |
|  6 |  20 |   300 |       0 |       1 |       0 |
|  7 |  20 |   400 |       0 |       0 |       1 |
|  8 |  30 |    10 |       1 |       0 |       0 |
+----+-----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I need to query the table and display the data as follows

```
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| Key | Orig Value | Prev Value | Curr Value |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
|  10 |       1000 | 3000       | 4000       |
|  20 |        100 | 300        | 400        |
|  30 |         10 | n/a        | n/a        |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
```

I was thinking on the following lines.

```
SELECT t1.key, t1.orig_value, t2.prev_value, t3.curr_value 
FROM (
(SELECT key, value as orig_value
 FROM statistics
 WHERE is_orig = 1
) AS t1, 
(SELECT key, value as prev_value
 FROM statistics
 WHERE is_prev = 1
) AS t2, 
(SELECT key, value as curr_value
 FROM statistics
 WHERE is_curr = 1
) AS t3
)
```

This works; but is there a better way to get the desired result?

Kindly note that is_orig=1, is_prev=1, and is_curr=1 are all mutually exclusive of each other. Hence, the three separate queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation like this:

```
select "Key", 
   MAX(CASE WHEN "Is_Orig" = 1 THEN "Value" END) "Orig Value",
   MAX(CASE WHEN "Is_Prev" = 1 THEN "Value" END) "Prev Value",
   MAX(CASE WHEN "Is_Curr" = 1 THEN "Value" END) "Curr Value"
from statistics
group by "Key"
```

The `CASE` statements select the value in each case and return `NULL` in the other cases. `MAX` is just to get that one value from the nulls.

Have a look at https://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot for some background. It also refers to an Oracle specific feature called "modeling" that allows a similar thing.

Comment: Works like a charm; cannot thank you enough for this one.